# Javascript, dynamically create an empty object copy during a map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to find a good solution to process my array of objects.

I have two arrays:

```
let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","small","small","small"]

let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
            {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
            {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":2}, 
            {"id":9,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":3}, 
            {"id":11,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":4}]
```

**Edit: Items are more complex than this: it has about 15 attributes...**

`structure` has a dynamic length and is my reference array. When I change `structure` I must remap the items array changing the format according to `structure`. So if I change `structure` to

```
let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","vertical","vertical","small"]
```

The array must change to

```
 let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
              {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
              {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":2}, 
              {"id":9,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":3}, 
              {"id":11,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":4}]
```

This can be done with a map. 
This is my Vue method, I map the structure and use the function `changeStructure` I change the format.

```
methods: {
      changeStructure(object,structure) {
        object.format = structure
        return object
      },
      updateCoverElements() {
        let structure = this.coverTypes[this.currentCoverVersion]
        let elements = this.coverElements
        let changeStructure = this.changeStructure

        let revisedElement = structure.map(function(structure, index) {
          return changeStructure(elements[index],structure)
        });
        console.log(revisedElement);
      }
    },
```

But the problem is that, as I told before, **structure has a dynamic length**.

So when I change to

```
let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","vertical"]
```

Item results must be

```
let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
            {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
            {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":2}]
```

This is not a problem, if the new `structure` length has less elements.

But when I change to

```
let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical"]
```

Item results must be

```
let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
             {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
             {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":2},
             {"id":"","title":"","format":"vertical","position":3}, 
             {"id":"","title":"","format":"vertical","position":4},
             {"id":"","title":"","format":"vertical","position":5}, 
             {"id":"","title":"","format":"vertical","position":6}]
```

And here is the problem: I cannot find a good way to dynamically create an object with the same identical structure as other items objects (a copy), with every field empty except for position, the index of the array, and format.

Comment: This seems like an unusual design decision--why are you keeping those objects with empty `id` and `title` attributes in your bottom-most example?

Comment: I'm creating some empty slots, later with drag & drop I will drop some "contents" and I fill the id and the title

Comment: Why not just remove the items from the array when structure is short, then grow the array when structure is long? A clean solution to this problem might involve refactoring some of that contextual code...

Comment: When the items are short they are auto removed from the structure, because If I map structure (lenght 4) and items are 5 last item is auto-dropped. My issue is structure lenght > item lenght

Comment: I just updated my answer to handle cases where structure is < and > your items. That said, this design seems a little strange to me still, so you might want to consider showing it to some other JS devs you know to get their thoughts...

Comment: This is a Vue app that I'm using to create a form to submit in Rails... every item is a block of a structure that I have to fill with drag and drop... is ok. The issue here is that my object is a bit more complex

Comment: Well as long as you're comfortable with the design then all is well. Feel free to check out the updates I posted below--they'll handle cases where structure is longer or shorter than your items. If you want to keep mutating `items`, just set `var items = _items` after the bottom-most line in my snippet below. That said I see dangers in this approach (you'll lose your title and id attributes over time, for example...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this. If `items` has a value at the `index`, it will overwrite the default `id` and `title` values.

```js
let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical","vertical"]

let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
            {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
            {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":2}]

const defaultObj = { id: '', title: '' }

const newItems = structure.map((format, position) => {
  return { ...defaultObj, ...items[position], format, position }
})

console.log(newItems)
```

Comment: But then if the attributes of items change (e.g. `title` gets changed to `itemTitle`) he has to change this function as well :/

Comment: @duhaime There is no indication in the question for any of that. We answer to the [mcve] provided in the question. This answer works for when structure is bigger or smaller than `items`

Comment: Sure, but I'd say one should also try to provide non-brittle code when possible. I mention the note above in case it may be relevant to the OP...

Comment: @duhaime From what I see, OP wants to update `format` and `position` of items based on `structure` (And your answer doesn't update `position` when `structure`'s length is > `items`)

Comment: Oh I see, he had a few things going on in the question and I didn't read the end!

Comment: @adiga this could be the best solution, but of course my I simplify my item object... is has about 15 attributes :-)

Comment: @adiga I can create an empty object with all the attributes... how can I change this function to use my empty object?

Comment: @RobertoPezzali you mean like a default object with empty `id`, `title` etc?

Comment: @adiga yes, I have this default object

Comment: @RobertoPezzali does the update work? You can create a default obejct with all the properties you need. Then use the spread syntax to merge `defaultObj` and `items[index]` if it exists

Answer (score 1):

Just slice off a new copy of items with max `structure.length` items, then iterate through your new clone of items and set each `format` attribute. Finally, create new objects for any elements in `structure` that don't have a corresponding partner in `items`:

```js
var structure = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

var items = [
  {'id':1,'title':'xxxxx','format':'horizontal','position':0}, 
  {'id':3,'title':'xxxxx','format':'vertical',  'position':1}, 
  {'id':6,'title':'xxxxx','format':'vertical',  'position':2},
];

// update all extant items
var _items = Object.assign([], items.slice(0, structure.length));
_items.forEach(function(i, idx) { i.format = structure[idx] });

// create any new items
for (var i=_items.length; i<structure.length; i++) {
  _items.push(Object.assign({}, items[0], {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    position: i,
    format: structure[i],
  }))
}

console.log(_items)
```

Comment: I try but if structure lenght is 7 _items remain 5. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Check out the updates (I hadn't read the second half of your question). I'd recommend learning some of these primitive operations in JS before rushing to fancy ES6 notation. Once you have a vocabulary of basic operations in JS you'll be able to use ES6 as a shortcut, but you'll be able to spell out more elaborate operations nice and simply...

Comment: ok, I thing this approach is ok. By the way my item object is more complex, about 15 attributes.

Comment: Yes, check out Object.assign. It will create a new object of type {{arg 0}}, then copy all attributes and values from {{arg 1}}, then override any attributes and values from {{arg 2}}: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign. So you can copy all boilerplate attributes from some object. If you need greater help with this task, though, I'd ask another question (after reading the MDN docs and giving Object assign a whirl)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem using `map()` method would be to organize your implementation functional so that you could call it many times with a different set of data wherever you need (the concept of reusability).

Here is what I have tried. I have defined the function named `getAlteredArray(items, structure)` which returns the desired array. Note that if you are looking to use **map()** method means you want a new array (I mean you don't want to alter the passed array).

> I have pasted the **o/p** on the code itself (it is commented out).

```
// function that creates new array with desired items and returns to the caller
function getAlteredArray(items, structure) {
    let newArr = items.map((obj, index) => {
        // obj => {"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}
        obj["format"] = structure[index]
        return obj
    })

    return newArr
}

// function that creates set of data needs to be passed to getAlteredArray() function
function test() {
    let items = [{"id":1,"title":"xxxxx","format":"horizontal","position":0}, 
            {"id":3,"title":"xxxxx","format":"vertical","position":1}, 
            {"id":6,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":2}, 
            {"id":9,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":3}, 
            {"id":11,"title":"xxxxx","format":"small","position":4}]

    // TEST 1 - Call getAlteredArray() with `items` & `structure`
    let structure = ["horizontal","vertical","vertical","vertical","small"]
    let newArr = getAlteredArray(items, structure)
    console.log(newArr)
    /*
        [ { id: 1, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'horizontal', position: 0 },
          { id: 3, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'vertical', position: 1 },
          { id: 6, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'vertical', position: 2 },
          { id: 9, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'vertical', position: 3 },
          { id: 11, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'small', position: 4 } ]
    */

    // TEST 2 
    let structure2 = ["horizontal","vertical","small","small","small"]
    let newArr2 = getAlteredArray(items, structure2)
    console.log(newArr2)
    /*
        [ { id: 1, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'horizontal', position: 0 },
          { id: 3, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'vertical', position: 1 },
          { id: 6, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'small', position: 2 },
          { id: 9, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'small', position: 3 },
          { id: 11, title: 'xxxxx', format: 'small', position: 4 } ]    
    */
}

// Start
test()
```